# OpenCV Android Studio Set-up problems

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I am trying to use opencv in android studio but am having some problems. I have searched the forums but couldn't find this exact problem. I am clicking file > import module and entering the following file path: OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\sdk\java

I then receive an import summary like this:

## ECLIPSE ANDROID PROJECT IMPORT SUMMARY

### Ignored Files:

The following files were *not* copied into the new Gradle project; you
should evaluate whether these are still needed in your project and if
so manually move them:

- javadoc\
- javadoc\allclasses-frame.html
- javadoc\allclasses-noframe.html
- javadoc\constant-values.html
- javadoc\help-doc.html
- javadoc\index-all.html
- javadoc\index.html
- javadoc\org\
  ...
  the summary includes a lot more libraries that are not included but I didn't want to list pointless additional information.
  ...

### Moved Files:

Android Gradle projects use a different directory structure than ADT
Eclipse projects. Here's how the projects were restructured:

- AndroidManifest.xml => openCVLibrary2410\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
- lint.xml => openCVLibrary2410\lint.xml
- res\ => openCVLibrary2410\src\main\res\
- src\ => openCVLibrary2410\src\main\java\
- src\org\opencv\engine\OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl => openCVLibrary2410\src\main\aidl\org\opencv\engine\OpenCVEngineInterface.aidl

### Next Steps:

You can now build the project. The Gradle project needs network
connectivity to download dependencies.

### Bugs:

If for some reason your project does not build, and you determine that
it is due to a bug or limitation of the Eclipse to Gradle importer,
please file a bug at http://b.android.com with category
Component-Tools.

(This import summary is for your information only, and can be deleted
after import once you are satisfied with the results.)

Can anyone help me with this issue please?

Answer (score 2):

Even if ".html" files are not copied the code will work.
Instead of importing path:"OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk\sdk\java" import any one of the samples from the opencv sdk 4 android and the libraries will be imported automatically
 eg:-(path:"OpenCV-2.4.11-android-sdk\OpenCV-android-sdk\samples\15-puzzle")
 then you can always remove the module from properties.